# Powershell Clear-Host alternative to preserve the buffer

Tags: windows, powershell, buffer, newline

I would like something like Clear-Host, but would like the scrollback.

So far, all I have is basically adding newlines until the screen is clear.  Though when I do this, the cursor starts writing at the bottom of the page (as to be expect- though not desired).

I would hope to start writing at the top of the page (for menus and such- which is the natural thing to do)

This is the code to print the dynamic count of new lines:

```
do {Write-Host ""; $i++}
while ($i -ne $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height)
```

I did see something about a Transcript module, but do not desire that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to build an ui you could also just go all the way and use windows forms instead of fiddling around with the console window

Comment: I've been trying to stay away from that.  I'd have to load the software on to the Work machine and I have much more experience with command line (unix primarily).  Which is why I thought Clear-Host was so odd compared to clear in Unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a one-liner which gives exactly what you're looking for:

```
[System.Console]::SetWindowPosition(0,[System.Console]::CursorTop)
```

From here:
http://tommymaynard.com/ql-clear-host-without-clearning-the-host/

The linked article also show how to use this in a Function for repeated use in a script.

Comment: That's perfect!  For those who don't want to read a few pages:

`[System.Console]::SetWindowPosition(0,[System.Console]::CursorTop)`