# Keyboard-Buffer in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, device, keyboard-events

In Linux it is possible to read keystrokes directly from a device file. The device file is located under / dev / input / event *.
Is there a similar possibility under Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Windows devices are not organized that way (most are specialized rather than generic).  There are legacy names such as `CON` which have no associated path but can be referenced in a batch file, while the newer ones (which also can be referenced by name) generally require specialized drivers.

For more information on the legacy names:

- *[What's the deal with those reserved filenames like NUL and CON?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/22/55388.aspx)*
- *[Device Names for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293924%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)*
- *[MS-DOS Device Driver Names Cannot be Used as File Names](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/74496)*

The place to start with newer devices names is in the [Windows Driver Kit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In particular [`DevCon.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows (and manipulates) these.

Of course, you can manipulate devices with PowerShell:

- *[Device Management PowerShell Cmdlets Sample - An introduction](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wincat/archive/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction.aspx)*
- *[Logging Keys with PowerShell: Get-Keystroke](http://obscuresecurity.blogspot.com/2013/06/Get-Keystroke.html)*
- *[Powershell Clear-Host alternative to preserve the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001404/powershell-clear-host-alternative-to-preserve-the-buffer)*